# How do I get state duration in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have a PowerBI table containing the time at which each state was entered:

```
Object | State | Start |
  1        A       0
  2        A       0
  3        B       0
  1        B       3
  2        B       4
  1        C       5
```

And now I want to create a calculated column showing the amount of time in each state for each object, e.g. given the above data I would expect the output to look like this:

```
Object | State | Start | Calculated Column |
  1        A       0             3
  2        A       0             4
  3        B       0             10
  1        B       3             2
  2        B       4             6
  1        C       5             5
```

(Assuming current time is 10)

Note that the state seuqences are not necessarily known. They are `A`, `B`, `C` in my example, but they are hash values in the real case.

How can I do this in PowerBI/DAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried:

```
Column = 
var CurrentTime = 10 
var CurrentObj = Table1[Object]
var CurrentStart = Table1[Start]
var CurrentState = Table1[State]
var NextStart = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(Table1[Start],1=1), FILTER(Table1, Table1[State] = CurrentState + 1),FILTER(Table1, Table1[Object]=CurrentObj))

RETURN IF(ISBLANK(NextStart), CurrentTime - CurrentStart,NextStart - CurrentStart)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Pratik - thanks for this. In my real example though, the "state" is a hash code, and the next state is not known, so the _CurrentState + 1_ part won't work. I've adjustd my example to reflect this. How would you solve it in this instance?

Comment: I solved this by replacing `FILTER(Table1, Table1[State] = CurrentState + 1)` with `FILTER(Table1, Table1[Start] > CurrentStart), FILTER(Table1, MIN(Table1[Start]))`

Comment: If hashcode is in proper order then this will work fine for you :)